# Buscar "patron" en string C#

Tags: c#, string

¿Existe algun metodo para buscar un patron con unas caracteristicas en concreto dentro de un string?
Necesito mirar en un string y si alguna de las partes contiene un `(xxxxxxx)` eliminarlo, el problema esta en que lo que hay dentro del parentesis puede ser variable pero siempre tendra la misma longitud, es decir si lo que hay dentro del parentesis tiene 7 caracteres deseo eliminarlo pero si no, mantenerlo tal cual.

Comment: Hola Edulon. Buscas usar [tag:regex] imagino. Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de string y lo que quieres eliminar explicanod que caracteristicas tiene para identificarlo? Añade tambien algo que hayas probado para que sobre eso podamos explicarte y ayudarte. Mira [ask] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Tienes varias opciones, pero parece un trabajo perfecto para una [Expresión Regular](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular)

Comment: utiliza nombreDeString.Replace(patron, "");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mejor es que utilices una [Expresión Regular](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular) utilizando el método [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx).

En tu caso, este código haría lo que quieres:

```
string cadena = "Esto es una cadena(as12eth) de (asfghjk)prueba";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\(.{7}\)");
cadena = rgx.Replace(cadena, "");
//resultado: cadena="Esto es una cadena de prueba"
```

Explicación del regex:

```
\( - busca el carácter `(`
.  - cualquier carácter
{7}- que se repita 7 veces
\) - carácter `)`
```

Comment: Gracias! es precisamente lo que buscaba, ¿Puedo decirle a la expresion regular que la repeticion de caracteres sea 7, 8 u 9 en la misma instruccion?
Gracias

Comment: @Edulon si, sustituyendo `{7}` por `{7,9}`